# limit of sequence with given condition

Tags: limits

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence with the property that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(a_{n+1}-a_n)=1$.

Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \infty$ and $\sqrt[n]{a_n} = 1$

---

I just want to know if it's ok how I solved it.

Proof:

For the first part $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(a_{n+1}-a_n)=1 \Longrightarrow$ there exists a rank $n_\epsilon$ such that $\forall n>n_\epsilon$, $|n(a_{n+1}-a_n)-1|<\epsilon$, or $a_{n+1}-a_n>\frac{1-\epsilon}{n}$, equivalently $a_{n+1}>a_n+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{\epsilon}{n}$, $\forall n>n_\epsilon$. Taking $n$ to $\infty$ and summing up all the inequalities untill $n_\epsilon$,

we get $a_{n} > a_{n_\epsilon}$+ $(H_n-H_{n_\epsilon})-(n-n_\epsilon)\frac{\epsilon}{n}= a_{n_\epsilon}$+ $(H_n-H_{n_\epsilon})-(1-\frac{n_\epsilon}{n})\epsilon$. ($H_n$= is the n-th harmonic number). As  $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}H_n = \infty$, is clear that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n =\infty$.

For the second part using Cauchy-D'alambert it's equivalent to finding the limit of $y_n=\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$. The initial condition can be rewritten as $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n a_n(y_{n}-1)=1$, so again there exists a rank $n_\epsilon$ such that $\forall n>n_\epsilon$, $|n a_n(y_{n}-1)-1|<\epsilon$ which means $(y_{n}-1)<\frac{1+\epsilon}{n a_n}$, but $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n a_n= \infty$ so $(y_{n}-1)<\frac{1+\epsilon}{n a_n}<\epsilon$ which precisely means that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n=1$.

Are the approaches I used correct?

Comment: Is the $\epsilon$ on the left-hand side of $\frac{1+\epsilon}{na_n}\lt \epsilon$ the same as the $\epsilon$ on the right-hand side?  The first part looks fine, but I would rather fix $\epsilon=1/2$ say. Then obtain upper and lower bounds for $a_n$, for large enough $n$, and take the $n$-th root, use squeezing.

Comment: I could not follow the last part of your "Part 1."  It looks like summing $a_{n+1}-a_n > (1-\epsilon)/n$  over $n \in \{n_{\epsilon}+1, ..., m-1\}$ would give $a_m - a_{n_\epsilon+1} > (1-\epsilon)\sum_{n=n_{\epsilon}+1}^{m-1}1/n$. So, I do not know where your "$(n-n_{\epsilon})\epsilon/n$" term comes from. I also agree that you can just take $\epsilon=1/2$.

Comment: For the first part see: [Proving that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n(a_{n+1}-a_{n})=1 \implies a_n$ diverges to $\infty$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1237275).

Comment: And for the second part you can probably use the fact that $\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}{1/n}=1$ (see, for example, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129272/find-lim-x-to-infty-leftx-left-ln-leftx1-right-ln-x-right-right) and [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100338/limit-of-quotient-of-two-series/100542#100542).